# Add an image on top of the main image in fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm displaying a number of images...

```
<div id="gallery"> 
    <a href="photos/pic1.jpg" rel="lightbox-left" title=""> 
        <img src="photos/pic1_2.jpg" /></a> 

    <a href="photos/pic2.jpg" rel="lightbox-left" title="my title" class="flag"> 
        <img src="photos/pic2_2.jpg"  /></a>
</div>
```

What I'm wanting is for the entry with a class of 'flag' to have a small flag image displayed on the smaller image (eg. pic2_2.jpg) AND on the main fancybox image (eg. pic2.jpg).

The first part I've achieved using the following (I'm adding the overlayed image as a background image)

```
$("<img src='/images/empty.png' class='overlay' />").insertAfter("a.flag img");
```

with CSS of

```
img.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 21px;
    background-image: url(/images/flag.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border:none !important;
}
```

however I'm having difficulty solving the second part of the problem, i.e. to superimpose an image on the fancybox main picture.

I've got some sort of control by adding an image to the title and then moving it around with CSS but don't seem to be able to find a position to move it to which will work with any size image.  What I've tried is

```
   $('#gallery a').fancybox({
        beforeShow: function () {
            if (this.title) {
                this.title = "<img src='/images/flag.png' class='moveflag' />" + this.title;
            }
            else {
                this.title = "<img src='/images/flag.png' class='moveflag' />";
            }
        }
    });
```

with CSS of

```
.moveflag {
    position:absolute;
    top:-50px;
    left:5px;
 }
```

If I could get hold of sizes and positions of the fancybox components then I could build an explicit style to move the image to where I want but I've been unable to find such information.

So, what I'm after is either a better way of overlaying this small image on the picture or some way of getting the various sizes so I can place it reliably where I want it.

I would also point out that at this stage this solution hasn't even started to look at applying the effect only to the pictures with a class of 'flag'.  First I need to be able to generate the effect I want!

Comment: BTW, I should have added that I'm using fancybox 2.1.3 with jquery 1.7.2

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/wCmed/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `insertBefore` rather than `insertAfter` in

```
$("<img src='/images/empty.png' class='overlay' />").insertAfter("a.flag img");
```

Because the `overlay` is positioned absolutely, it would not affect the position of the real image. However, you will need to manage `z-index` in CSS in such a way that your overlay has a greater `z-index` than your original picture.

Comment: As I said, I've got that part working but surely it doesn't make any difference whether that image is inserted before or after the existing one, since it's being positioned absolutely and so relies on their mutual container.

Comment: Oh, I see, I misinterpreted the question a bit. However, the point is that by using `insertBefore` you can avoid setting `top`/`left` coordinates in the CSS for the flag. Unfortunately, I don't use `fancybox` so I cannot help with the second part of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your interest and I see your logic now, though I want to move the image away from the edges anyway, so I'd still need top and left or some similar method.